# A measure for the "typicalness" of a Brownian path

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Suppose I have a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, and I wish to measure somehow how similar it is, in some sense, to a Brownian motion $\{B(t)\mid t\in[0,1]\}$ (with $B(0)=0$).

I was wondering whether there are off-shelf measures for such a similarity, perhaps something like the Berry–Esseen theorem... if not, I was coming up with an idea, and I wonder what do you think about it:

- Let $T = \{(t,B(t))\mid t\in[0,1]\}$ be the (random) trajectory of a Brownian motion at times $[0,1]$.
- For a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, let $f^{(\varepsilon)}=\{(t,f(t)+\delta t)\mid t\in[0,1],\ \delta\in[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]\}$ be the "expanded" graph of $f$.
- Define $\rho^{(\varepsilon)}:C([0,1])\to[0,1]$ to be the "$\varepsilon$-typicalness" measure of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ as follows:
  \begin{equation*}
    \rho^{(\varepsilon)}(f) = \mathbb{P}\left(T\subseteq f^{(\varepsilon)}\right).
  \end{equation*}

I am not entirely sure what happens near $0$. Do you think that the $\varepsilon$-typicalness of *every* function $f$, for *every* $\varepsilon$, will be $0$ as it is defined now? If so, can you think of a minor correction?

Comment: Why do you think that the $\varepsilon$-typicalness as defined would be zero for every $f\in C([0,1])$? If I had to hazard a guess I'd agree because Brownian motions are not Lipschitz continuous so a linearly increasing bound ($+\delta t$) will not be sufficient to bound the trajectories. Disclaimer: this is just me thinking out loud ;)

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a good measure for the "typicalness". What *is* (for me) typical for Brownian paths is e.g. the roughness of the paths, i.e. that there are nowhere differentiable and that the local minima/maxima are dense. But the here defined measure doesn't given any information about all of this (because it basically measures that the BM is not too far away from the function).

Comment: Well, in fact I am thinking of $f$ as some smoothing or interpolation of samples taken from some underlying distribution, thus I don't really care about the roughness.